# Removing outliers from a list of list in python

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension, outliers

I have this data in Python which is a list of list. What I would like to do is to find any outlier in the second column, i.e, data[0][1], data[1][1] and etc. and then remove that list from data. for example here, clearly 90 is the outlier and I want to remove that list containing 90, i.e, remove [0.5,80] from data. I have tried this but I think the last part is not right. Any idea how can I do this using list comprehensions?

```
data= [[0.5549872122762148, 41.176470588235304],
             [0.575197889182058, 33.55145118733509],
             [0.5561224489795918, 38.60204081632651],
             [0.5, 90]]

data_median = np.median(data, axis = 0)
data_std = np.std(data, axis = 0)
cut_off = data_std * 3
lower, upper = data_median - cut_off, data_median + cut_off
dataout = [[y for y in x if y if y < lower or y > upper] for x in data]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
dataout = [[x,y] for x,y in data if (lower[0] < x < upper[0]) and 
                                    (lower[1] < y < upper[1])]
```

But your `cut_off` is too permissive.
Try instead with:

```
cut_off = data_std * 1
```